# Does gluon support Xpath in IOS

Tags: xpath, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

I tried running a gluon project that uses XML to initialize the project. Seeing the following error when running the application on an IOS device:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFactory implementation found for the object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:76

Note: Application runs successfully on Desktop Windows/Mac and on Android platform.

Is the Xpath not supported on IOS devices with Gluon

Comment: Can you at least post the project dependencies? A short code snippet on how you call XPath will help as well.

Comment: Error is thrown at : private static final XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()

The following are the dependency :
  // Desktop SQL -> https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'
   
    //desktopRuntime 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.148'
    
    // Embedded SQL -> https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    embeddedRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'

    // Android SQL -> https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
    
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the exception:

```
No XPathFactory implementation found for the object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance...
```

So all you need to do is provide a valid implementation.

For instance, adding this to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.0'
    compile 'xalan:xalan:2.7.2'
}
```

Probably there are others like `'com.sun.org.apache:jaxp-ri:1.4'`.

I've tried it for this code only:

```
public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    XPath newXPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
}
```

and I don't get the exception anymore.

Comment: Good. Consider accepting this answer as valid (check to the left), so it can be useful for others as well.